# How to play an animation on a mesh?

Tags: rendering, animation

I have a pre-rendered animation that I want to play on a TV model in my new scene animation, and I really don't know how.

Would I do it within Blender, or should I make the material on the TV screen green, so I can green-screen it on?

Comment: You could use an animated texture to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "TV"? Are you talking about the TV clips, or the real device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Blender Internal:

1. Add a new texture and set the type to *image or movie*.
2. Select a file, then set the *[source](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Image#Image)* to either *Sequence* or *Movie* depending on the format your rendered animation is in. (e.g. *Sequence* for an image sequence, or *Movie* for a single video file.)

## Cycles:

1. Add a new [*Image Texture*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html) node and open a file.
2. Add an image file to the node, or pick an existing image, then set the *Source* to either *Sequence* or *Movie* (this option will only appear after you select an image file), again depending on the format your rendered animation is in.

[image]

Comment: I always render out image sequences. Its a force of habit since i've had to work with such crappy computers in the past. Anyways, thanks man.

Comment: @Starius me too... it is more fail-safe that way

Comment: This is nice, however I am looking for more advanced possibility to control the speed also of the playback independent from global animation speed, I could do this via the amount of source images to be selected, but within Blender would be better?

Comment: @Thomas It is a hack and a bit of a fuss to set up but that is possible this way: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15855/599