# Is there a way to erase all image data blocks for a specific .blend?

Tags: image, data-blocks

When I no longer need the images, sifting through the image data blocks (or even typing the name) can be time-consuming in repetition. Especially when images have the same or similar prefixes.

[image: Image data blocks]

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `.001` `.002` ... I see at the end of the names would indicate the image blocks have been duplicated. See if this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46060/935) is any help.

Unless you see a `0` between the preview and the image name, then the image is linked to something. Only when this user count is zero will the blocks be removed when saving the file. The image may be used by an image node in your materials which you may have duplicated, or it could be a brush texture that you may have created multiple times, 3DView background images, the list goes on.

[image: image list]

Answer (score 2):

When you have a data block that has no users it will automatically be removed when you save your project and reload the file.

Blender does not delete data right away as someone may have a use for it still. An example is if something has been imported/linked/appended and has not been assigned to an object yet. Obviously you want it to stay in memory until it is given a user or else it would be gone as quickly as it was loaded!

To recap simply save your scene and reopen it and all your unused content will go away. With the exception of data that you have specifically told blender not to delete even if it has no users. (You can do that by pressing the button with the letter 'F' on it.)

Comment: The data blocks do not go away, the ones seen above are weeks old. I've saved, closed and reopened the file multiple times. I know how to save a data block, but have never done so in this file.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot I had actually appended a few objects.